# Isomorphism between structures

Tags: logic, group-isomorphism

I have gotten the next structures:
$$M_1=\langle \mathbb{N},S^{M_1}=\{\langle n,k\rangle\in \mathbb{N}^2:\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(n-k=2m) \} \rangle$$
$$M_2=\langle \mathbb{Z},S^{M_2}=\{\langle a,b\rangle\in \mathbb{Z}^2:\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(a-b=2m) \} \rangle$$
$$M_3=\langle \mathbb{Q},S^{M_3}=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in \mathbb{Q}^2:\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(x-y=2m) \} \rangle$$

Now, I have the find the isomorphic structures.

---

In my opinion, there isn't isomorphism at all between the next structures, because there are negative numbers at $M_2$ and in $M_3$ there are fractions numbers whose difference is an integer and an even number, so I don't see a bijective function between them. I will be glad for some help. Thanks!

Comment: In English, it's more natural to write "I have the following structures" instead of "I have gotten the next structures". In general, if you're referring to a list of things, it's better to use "following" instead of "next".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M_1$ and $M_2$ are equivalence relations, where all even integers become equivalent, and likewise for odd integers. So can you find a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ that preserves parity?

In $M_3$ we also have an equivalence relation, but many more classes.... Can you show that isomorphisms preserve the number of classes under a relation? Or note that in $M_1,M_2$ the statement

$$\forall x,y,z \in M: xSy \lor xSz \lor ySz$$

holds in $\langle M,S\rangle$ and in $M_3$ it does not..

Comment: Oh that's right. So $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isomorphic, while $M_3$ isn't isomorphic to any of $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: @aasc232 formalise that in the framework you're working with..

Comment: Yes, thank you! I missed that the relations of N and Z are both the same.

Comment: @aasc232 not the same but *isomorphic*..

Comment: Btw, only $M_1$ and $M_2$ hold the sentence you gave, is that telling me that $M_3$ cannot be isomorphic to $M_1$ or $M_2$?

Comment: @aasc232 yes, indirectly.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I have one more question. While I am trying to expand the question, such that instead of those structures I would have the next structures:
$$M_1=\langle (0,5),S^{M_1}=\{\langle n,k\rangle\in (0,5)^2:\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(n-k=2m) \} \rangle$$
$$M_2=\langle (3,8),S^{M_2}=\{\langle a,b\rangle\in (3,8)^2:\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(a-b=2m) \} \rangle$$
$$M_3=\langle (0,8),S^{M_3}=\{\langle x,y\rangle\in (0,8)^2:\exists m\in \mathbb{Z}(x-y=2m) \} \rangle$$. I see that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are still isomorphic with $h(x)=x+3$ from $M_1$ to $M_2$, is that right?

Comment: Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: @aasc232 Then all $3$ become isomorphic I think.

Comment: I know that $M_1$ and $M_2$, but what is the function between $M_2$ and $M_3$

Comment: @aasc232 Oh no, there is a statement that holds in $M_3$ but not in $M_1,M_2$. I'll leave it as a puzzle to you.

Comment: I will! However, what do you say about $h(x)=x+3$ from $M_1$ to $M_2$ is it true?

Comment: @aasc232 yes that works as the function preserves distances.

Comment: Thank you Henno :)